# R: Pander does not correctly number summary tables from regression output

Tags: r, pander

I am using pander to print regression output. However, it is automatically (incorrectly) labeling the tables.  I have tried to use `setcaption` to override this habit, but it simply puts the caption to the right of the automated table number.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You should give a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of a document that ends up with incorrect table numbers. It's hard to say what you might be doing wrong without seeing your code.

Comment: `pander` generates pandoc's markdown, where you cannot specify the table numbers, as that's computed (incremented) automatically in your resulting document in a format specific to the output file format/stylesheet/template. See more details at http://pandoc.org/README.html#extension-table_captions